# How to use html5 drag-drop functionality with FileSystemAPI?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, html5-filesystem, native-file-system-api-js

I am using the **FileSystemAPI** **window.showDirectoryPicker()** to open a directory which is returning a handle to that directory & by using that I can traverse all the files present in that directory.

```
const dropArea = document.getElementById("drop_zone");
dropArea.onclick = async (evt) => {
  const dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
  // Next lines of code using dirHandle 
};
```

Above piece of code working fine when use clicking on the button which is prompting the user to chose a directory.
I want to achieve the same functionality with the drag & drop as well, means instead of clicking & choosing a directory user can drop a directory.

Followed below link but it didn't work for me.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/07/Drag-and-drop-a-folder-onto-Chrome-now-available#how_to_handle_dropped_folders

I will appreciate for any help or input on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The
[HTML Drag and Drop interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)
enable web applications to accept
[dragged and dropped files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop)
on a web page. During a drag and drop operation, dragged file and directory items are associated
with file entries and directory entries respectively. The `DataTransferItem.getAsFileSystemHandle()`
method returns a promise with a `FileSystemFileHandle` object if the dragged item is a file, and a
promise with a `FileSystemDirectoryHandle` object if the dragged item is a directory. The listing
below shows this in action. Note that the Drag and Drop interface's
[`DataTransferItem.kind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/kind)
will be `"file"` for both files *and* directories, whereas the File System Access API's
[`FileSystemHandle.kind`](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/#dom-filesystemhandle-kind) will
be `"file"` for files and `"directory"` for directories.

```js
elem.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
  // Prevent navigation.
  e.preventDefault();
});

elem.addEventListener('drop', async (e) => {
  // Prevent navigation.
  e.preventDefault();
  // Process all of the items.
  for (const item of e.dataTransfer.items) {
    // Careful: `kind` will be 'file' for both file
    // _and_ directory entries.
    if (item.kind === 'file') {
      const entry = await item.getAsFileSystemHandle();
      if (entry.kind === 'directory') {
        handleDirectoryEntry(entry);
      } else {
        handleFileEntry(entry);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Instead of iterating over e.dataTransfer.items can we directlly use e.dataTransfer.items[0]? if we are dropping a single directory?

Comment: You could, but if you only want to accept one for now, I'd just stop iterating after processing it (this allows you to later accept more directories when you change your mind).